# search for files in a path bottom up bash

Tags: bash, search

Using bash scripting, I am looking to try to search for a file based upon a path, however I would like to search from the bottom of the path up.  something like /path/to/directory/here and then search "here" for a file ".important" , then go up to "directory" and search for ".important" and so forth up the tree.  I don't want to recurse downward an any point in the path.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough once you understand string manipulation in bash.

```
dest=/path/to/directory/here
curr=

# quote right-hand side to prevent interpretation as glob-style pattern
while [[ $curr != "$dest" ]]; do
  if [[ -e $curr/.important ]]; then
    printf 'Found ' >&2
    printf '%s\n' "$curr/.important"
  else
    printf '%s\n' "Not found at $curr" >&2
  fi
  rest=${dest#$curr/}  # strip $curr/ from $dest to get $rest
  next=${rest%%/*}     # strip anything after the first / from next
  [[ $next ]] || break # break if next is empty
  curr=$curr/$next     # otherwise, add next to curr and recur
done
```

See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe for more on the string expansion syntax used here.

---

Alternately:

```
( set -f; cd /; IFS=/; for dir in $dest; do
    cd "$dir" || break
    if [ -e .important ]; then
      pwd
      break
    fi
  done )
```

Key points:

- `set -f` disables globbing; otherwise, this will behave very badly for a directory named `*`.
- `IFS=/` sets string-splitting on expansion to operate on `/`.
- `for dir in $dest` **is only safe after the two above operations have been done.**
- `break`ing if `cd` fails is essential to ensure that your script is actually in the directory that it thinks it's in.

Note that this is done in a subshell (per the parenthesis) to prevent its changes to shell settings (the `set -f` and `IFS=`) from impacting the larger script. This means you can use it in `$()` and read its output via stdout into a shell variable, but that you can't set a variable inside it and expect that variable to still be set in the parent script.